# Crystal Report 9.2

Tags: crystal-reports

I am getting the following error when we add the Crystal Report Engine dll. The Crystal Report version we are using is V9.2. Can I get the correct code to open Crystal Report RPT file in Crystal Report Viewer?

> 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine\9.2.3300.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll' is attempting managed execution inside OS Loader lock. Do not attempt
>   to run managed code inside a DllMain or image initialization function
>   since doing so can cause the application to hang.

In application, if user tries to open a crystal report file. The PF Usgae goes high and Server almost hangs. Is the above error causing the server to Hang?

Comment: Is this from a Log or do you see this in a Debug Session

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I had to install the Crystal Report Runtime Engine for .NET Framework 4.0, on our server. The Engine was downloaded from link: http://businessobjects.com/jump/xi/crvs2010/.

While stepping through the code in debug mode in Visual Studio 2010 the message above was displayed. I supressed it in Visual Studio 2010. Under the menu

`Debug` > `Exceptions` > `Managed Debugging Assistants`

I then located `LoaderLock` and unchecked the `Thrown` checkbox.